# How do you contruct a large query for the Rally Custom Grid?

Tags: rally

I am trying to construct a query for a Rally Custom Grid.  I would like to select the user story if it is assigned to one of the 58 Iterations I have in my project.

This works;
((Iteration.Name = "sprint 1 - 1/1/2012 - 1/31/2012") or (Iteration.Name = "Sprint 1 - 1/24 - 2/1"))

But this doesn't;
((Iteration.Name = "sprint 1 - 1/1/2012 - 1/31/2012") or (Iteration.Name = "Sprint 1 - 1/24 - 2/1") or (Iteration.Name = "sprint 2 - 2/01/2012 - 2/29/2012"))

Is there a limitation in the query dialog?  Any suggestion for the other values?

Regards,
Jim

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit to the number of clauses.  You just need a few more parens.

One clause:

```
(Foo = Bar)
```

Two clause:

```
((Foo = Bar) AND (Bar = Baz))
```

Three clause:

```
(((Foo = Bar) AND (Bar = Baz)) AND (A = 1))
```

Comment: Is there a continue character so that I can have them on new lines?

Comment: You'll just have to use regular string concatenation.

'((Foo = Bar) AND ' +
'(Bar = Baz))'

Then you can break lines around the +.